# Preventing A Dropdown Container From Pushing Another Container

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am customizing a real estate based WordPress theme called "RealHomes".  I have a contact form ('.cfos_contact_form'), I want to be hidden initially.  When a user hovers over the "Contact Us" container ('.rh_cfos .rh_cfos_labels'), the contact form rolls down using jQuery.  But the problem is '.cfos_contact_form' is pushing the section below ('.wrapper-home-sections'), down.

I want the contact form to roll down and display over, on top of, the content/container ('.wrapper-home-sections').

**custom.js**

```
    $('.rh_cfos .rh_cfos_labels').on({
        mouseenter:function(){
        console.log("Testing mouse entering now");
         $( ".cfos_contact_form" ).slideDown( "slow", function() {
          
            });
        }, 
        mouseleave:function(){
        console.log("Testing mouse leaving now");
         // $( ".cfos_contact_form" ).slideUp( "slow", function() {
        
         //    });
        }
    });
```

**style.css** (the custom css)

```
/*Form wrapper*/
.rh_cfos_wrap {
    bottom:500px;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    border: 5px solid silver;
}

/*Form container*/
.rh_cfos{
    padding:10px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}

/*Container for Contact Us For more details text*/
.rh_cfos .rh_cfos_labels{
border: 5px solid orange;
}

/*The form itself*/
.cfos_contact_form {
    /*display:none;*/
    background-color: pink;
}
```

**main.css** (the base css for the theme)

```
/*Form wrapper*/
.rh_cfos_wrap { 
  display: block; 
  width: 100%; 
  position: absolute; 
  background: #fff; 
  max-width: 400px; 
  bottom: 53px; 
  right: 0; 
}

/*Form container*/
    .rh_cfos { 
      padding: 30px; 
      position: relative; 
    }

/*The contact form itself*/
.cfos_contact_form { 
  display: -webkit-box; 
  display: -webkit-flex; 
  display: -ms-flexbox; 
  display: flex; 
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; 
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; 
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  margin-left: -7.5px; 
  margin-right: -7.5px; 
  margin-bottom: 0; 
}
```

**HTML**
[image]

**Here is what the form and container below looks like before rolling down:**
[image]

**Here is what the form looks like rolled down pushing the container below it:**
[image]

Comment: Can you put it on a codepen or similar?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably `position: absolute;` on the dropdown element, and `position: relative;` on its parent. Absolutely positioned elements don't take up space and so they don't push other elements elsewhere.
Ideally, you also want the element that's on top to have a z-index when the one under it doesn't, or for the one on top to have a higher z-index than the lower one.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index
I made you a small example:

```css
[class*="top-div"] {
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
[class*="top-div"] > div > span {
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  z-index: 10;
}
[class*="top-div"] > div:hover > span {
  display: block;
}
.bottom-div {
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.top-div-two > div {
  position: relative;
}
.top-div-two > div > span {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-div">
  <div>
  Some text
  <span>Another Element</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-div"></div>

<div class="top-div-two">
  <div>
  Some text
  <span>Another Element</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-div"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for contributing to a possible solution here.  I appreciate it.  In your example, "bottom-div" is being pushed down.  I want it to stay there.  And if "top-div-two" extends further down I want it to cover "bottom-div"....that's the behavior I'm looking for.  I am dissecting the html now in a code editor.  I'll post more when I get my head completely around it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified a little better. I did two examples, one where it gets pushed down and one where the "Another Element" is absolutely positioned above the `bottom-div`; that would be `top-div-two` and that's the one you probably need. Both of these work on hover. Take a look at how `position:absolute` works as it may come in handy.